# Why does router connect to this ip?

Tags: networking, router

My router got disconnected and then this shows up in the router (linksys) router?
Check screenprint from the log:

[image]

100.66.180.13?

What kind of adress is that? Why is my router connected to this ip? 
It leads to:
http://whatmyip.co/info/whois/100.66.180.13

Comment: no thats not my ip adress, also the new adress I got after the disconnection says I am sitting in a town 100s of miles from my home.

Comment: Of course it is - and don't tell us that your adress is 10.0.0.2 or 127.0.0.1! Do you know what the IANA is?

Comment: Don't just remove important information for the question with an edit.

Answer (score 5):

It most definitely is your IP address. Your ISP is using [Carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT):

> IETF created RFC 6598, detailing Shared Address Space for use in ISP CGN deployments and NAT devices that can handle the same addresses occurring both on inbound and outbound interfaces. ARIN returned space to the IANA as needed for this allocation. **The allocated address block is 100.64.0.0/10.**

When connecting to services on the Internet, you will appear with any of the CGNAT system’s public IP addresses.

Comment: its not my local ip adress and its not my ip adress I use on the internet.

Comment: No, of course. Did you read the article on CGNAT? It’s a provider-local network. It is as “your IP address” as it gets.

Comment: Usually I have a a complete different ip adress/range - it for one dont start with 100., the reason why I am asking is this just showed up, and related to this I get a ip that is nowhere near my city so I am bit curious and worried whats going on.

Comment: IP addresses have, at the *very* best, a loose location. You can just forget about that. With CGNAT it’s impossible anyway. Your traffic appears on “the Internet” when it leaves your ISP’s network. This is different from before, where the Internet was literally on the other side of your router. Your ISP might have installed CGNAT recently. Just ask them!

Comment: The location has been the same for years and have differed very little from where I am sitting, now its a town 100s mile from here so this must be something else, I have to ask my provider I guess.

Comment: [RFC 6598 section 7](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6598#section-7) identifies the IPv4 address range.  Nicely done, Daniel B.